# Gruntfile.js Syntax error: Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue

Tags: gruntjs

This is my very first attempt at configuring a Gruntfile.js and i can't seem to figure out what's causing this "Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue. Aborted due to warnings." error. Can someone please help me figure out what's wrong with my code. Find source code below:

```
    'use strict';

    module.exports = function (grunt) {

    // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
    require('time-grunt')(grunt);

    // Automatically load required Grunt tasks
    require('jit-grunt')(grunt);

    // Define the configuration for all the tasks
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

   // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
          jshint: {
            options: {
              jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
              reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
            },

            all: {
              src: [
                'Gruntfile.js',
                'app/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
              ]
            }
          }      
    }),

    copy: {
    dist: {
    cwd: 'app',
    src: [ '**','!styles/**/*.css','!scripts/**/*.js' ],
    dest: 'dist',
    expand: true
    },

    fonts: {
    files: [
      {
        //for bootstrap fonts
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
        src: ['fonts/*.*'],
        dest: 'dist'
      }, {
        //for font-awesome
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: 'bower_components/font-awesome',
        src: ['fonts/*.*'],
        dest: 'dist'
      }
    ]
    }
    },

    clean: {
    build: {
    src: [ 'dist/']
    }
    });


    grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean',
    'jshint',
    'copy'
    ]);


        grunt.registerTask('build', [
      'jshint'
    ]);

    grunt.registerTask('default',['build']);

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined a task named default. A sample, really small gruntfile.js can be found below:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');

    grunt.initConfig({
        copy: {
            main: {
                files: [
                    { expand: true, src: ['**'], cwd: 'lib/font-awesome/fonts/', dest: 'fonts/', filter: 'isFile' },
                ]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['copy:main']);
};
```

So, in this file, I'm loading the NPM package called `grunt-contrib-copy`. Then in the config, I specify the config for the copy sub-task by giving it a name of main and including the rules below that. Each grunt sub-task has it's own format of options and configuration that you can follow. Finally, I'm saying that the Grunt task runner should have a task named default followed by an order of operations. The first (and only) in my case is the copy sub-task and the main ruleset. In your case, this may be copy:dist for the copy operation.

Hope that helps get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your help Jason but I have a definition for a task called 'default' similar to yours at the very bottom of my code but i still get the warning as though the default task doesn't exist at all. any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the syntax error. These characters ')};' closed the config in the wrong place (line 30) which disrupted the flow of the program. so i just had to remove them and put them in their rightful place way down on line 67.

Sorry it turned out to be just a silly mistake on my part and probably nothing relevant to anyone else.

Comment: What you posted in your original question wasn't properly formatted. You should make sure when you post code that you properly format it first. That may have helped. Glad you found it though.